# How to create html file to do automatic post request

Tags: html, forms, post, cookies, submit

i'm trying to create a file html thats, with jquery support, checks for some cookie. If that cookies are present, it fill a form and submit it ( everything on load! ). If cookies are not present, it shows a login form.

So what i'm trying to develope is a page with a login form for first access and for other accesses a "redirect" to another page on another domain.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>mylocalpage</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script src="http://mysite.com/jquery-cookie.js"></script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var ag = $.cookie("agenc");
                var op = $.cookie("oper");
                var pa = $.cookie("pass");
                if(ag==null || op==null || pa==null){
                    var loginBox = $('#login-box');
                    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
                    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
                    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

                    $(loginBox).css({ 
                        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
                    });
                    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
                }else{
                    $('#txtAgency_ext').val(ag);
                    $('#txtUsername_ext').val(op);
                    $('#txtPassword_ext').val(pa);
                    $('#form').submit();
                }
            });
            function saveData(){
                var ag = $('#txtAgency_ext').val(), op = $('#txtUsername_ext').val(), pa = $('#txtPassword_ext').val();
                if(ag.length>0 && op.length>0 && pa.length>0){
                    $.cookie("agenc",ag,{ expires: 365,path:"/" });
                    $.cookie("oper",op,{ expires: 365,path:"/" });
                    $.cookie("pass",pa,{ expires: 365,path:"/" });
                    $('#form').submit();
                }else{
                    alert('All field required!');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #mask {
    display: none;
    background: #000; 
    position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}

.login-popup{
    display:none;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;  
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* Safari, Chrome */
}

img.btn_close {
    float: right; 
    margin: -28px -28px 0 0;
}

fieldset { 
    border:none; 
}

form.signin .textbox label { 
    display:block; 
    padding-bottom:7px; 
}

form.signin .textbox span { 
    display:block;
}

form.signin p, form.signin span { 
    color:#999; 
    font-size:11px; 
    line-height:18px;
} 

form.signin .textbox input { 
    background:#666666; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #333;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    color:#fff; 
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:6px 6px 4px;
    width:200px;
}
        </style>
        <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
            <form method="post" id="form" name="login" action="http://a.page.com">
                <label>
                    <span>Agency</span>
                    <input id="txtAgency_ext" name="txtAgency_ext" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    <span>Operator</span>
                    <input id="txtUsername_ext" name="txtUsername_ext" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    <span>Password</span>
                    <input id="txtPassword_ext" name="txtPassword_ext" value="" type="password">
                </label>
          </form>
          <button class="button" onclick="saveData()">Save and submit!</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when form is submitted, the page is redirected to her self so it do infinite time the couple Submit->Redirect->submit->Redirect etc...
How can i solve? thanks!

EDIT:
WHAT HAPPEN IS HERE:

http://jsfiddle.net/x96qV/

Comment: You're storing plain text passwords in cookies? _Oh my dear lord_. Please read some 101 articles on authentication and [storing passwords](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Comment: no problem. customer doesn't need security on this form

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the flow of your app.

1. User clicks Submit button, which sets the cookies and submits the form. The page reloads.
2. The page loads and checks for cookies. They exist, so the `else` statement is executed. This includes the line `$('#form').submit();`, which submits the form. The page reloads.
3. Repeat step number 2, indefinitely.

So you need to remove the `$('#form').submit();` line to stop the form from submitting itself indefinitely.

Comment: ok.. the flow is correct. but how can i submit that form to give to the action page of form the right parameters ?

Comment: All you need to do is set the `action` property of the form to a different URL/page.

Comment: i set the URL/page of `action` not to the same page but to an URL of another domain!

Comment: Can you provide a demo of this happening?

Comment: Also, move your style tags into the `head`. Just to better validate your HTML.

Comment: see edit pls :) and thanks for ur help! ( pay attention: launch it with chrome because there is an alert inside the code that is called every page load.. if you can't hide alert for entire page session you risks to can't exit from that page )

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome, I enter my details and it transfers me to the green & purple page. I reload the jsFiddle and I instantly get redirected to the green & purple page. What browsers have you tried?